# How to set more that one node property using Cypher in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

When I want to set a node property value, I use

```
MATCH (c:City)
WHERE c.name = 'London'
SET c.population = 8900000
RETURN c;
```

How can I set more than one property within code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set more than one property divide the properties with coma, like this:

```
MATCH (c:City)
WHERE c.name = 'London'
SET c.population = 8900000, c.country = 'United Kingdom'
RETURN c;
```